# Difference between inheriting from std::iterator and explicitly typedefing its member types

Tags: c++

I thought there are no differences, but I'm confused because while reading [the draft of C++ standard](https://www.open-std.org/JTC1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3690.pdf), 24.5.1.1, reverse_iterator, I found that the `reverse_iterator` is inherited from `iterator` and also has explicit typedefs `difference_type`, `pointer`, and `reference`.

```
template <class Iterator>
class reverse_iterator : public
    iterator<typename iterator_traits<Iterator>::iterator_category,
             typename iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type,
             typename iterator_traits<Iterator>::difference_type,
             typename iterator_traits<Iterator>::pointer,
             typename iterator_traits<Iterator>::reference> {
    public:
        typedef Iterator iterator_type;
        typedef typename iterator_traits<Iterator>::difference_type difference_type;
        typedef typename iterator_traits<Iterator>::reference reference;
        typedef typename iterator_traits<Iterator>::pointer pointer;
```

Why is it written like this?

Comment: Just forget `std::iterator` (which was deprecated in C++17).

Comment: @康桓瑋 So you mean there are no differences?

Comment: @康桓瑋 It is not supposed to be used anymore at all (deprecated) and will probably be removed completely at some point. So it isn't really useful anymore to discuss potential differences. You shouldn't use it in new code.

Comment: @user17732522 You tagged the wrong person bro :)

Comment: @康桓瑋 Oops, too late to change, but they'll see it anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been in the standard since C++98, so it is going to be a bit hard to find some context for how it came about.

Here is a just a guess:

They may have wanted to inherit the iterator from `std::iterator` as a matter of policy to inherit all iterators from it (not sure about that).

But if you were to simply copy the exposition as is and try to use it as a definition of the interface of `reverse_iterator`, then these typedefs are required.

If you removed e.g. the typedef for `difference_type`, then you couldn't use it later in e.g. the declaration

```
reverse_iterator operator+ (difference_type n) const;
```

That is because `iterator<...>` is a *dependent* base class of the class, meaning the actual type of the base depends on a template parameter. It has a `difference_type` member, but members of dependent base classes cannot be named directly, since the compile can't know yet at the point of the template's definition what members the dependent base class has. They must be qualified, i.e. for a type like here you need to write `typename iterator_traits<Iterator>::difference_type` to access it.

They probably didn't want to repeat that long thing every time they mention `difference_type` but still keep it proper C++ code. So they simply introduce the typedef for convenience.

From the outside when referring to a `reverse_iterator<...>::difference_type` the typedef doesn't change anything. In terms of the interface, there isn't really any practical difference between inheriting from `iterator` and declaring the type aliases manually. The only difference is that you can test whether the iterator is inherited from `std::iterator`. And as discussed in the comments under the question, `std::iterator` has been deprecated in C++17 anyway and shouldn't be used anymore at all.

That would also explain why only the members that are referred to later are typedef'ed and not e.g. `iterator_category` and `value_category`.